# How to bind the data in "render" to the specified data after calculation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, uiview, frontend, nuxt.js

I want to multiply the unit 'count' and 'cost' in the same column of cells, and then load it on the 'money', and the 'money' is a data attribute value, but I can't bind this attribute after trying many times. How to do
Below is the code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJNNf.png)

```
  <card>
    <Table
      border
      :columns="preorder"
      :data="preorderitem"
      show-summary
    >
      <template
        slot-scope="scope"
        slot="name"
      >
        <strong>{{ scope.row.name }}</strong>
      </template>
      <template
        slot-scope="{ row, index }"
        slot="action"
      >
        <Button
          type="error"
          size="small"
          @click="remove(index)"
        >Delete</Button>
      </template>
    </Table>
  </card>
```

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      selectData: [],
      preorder: [
        {
          title: 'itemname',
          slot: 'name'
        },
        {
          title: 'cost',
          key: 'cost'
        },
        {
          title: 'count',
          key: 'count',
        },
        {
          title: 'money',
          key: 'money',
          render: (h, params) => {
            let str = params.row.cost * params.row.count;
            return h('span', {
              domProps: {
                innerHTML: str
              },
              on: {
                'on-change': e => {
                  this.preorderitem[params.row.money] = str;
                }
              }
            })
          }
        }
      ]
}
```

Comment: Create a computed value that returns `count*cost` and set that to be `money`

Answer (score 0):

A method will help you here :

in your example you can do the following :

```
methods:{ 
  getMoney(cost,count){
    return cost*count;
  }
}
```